# Supremum and Infimum of two variable function

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A Two variable function
$$f(x,y)=(x-2)^2 +(y-2)^2 $$
The Domain of x is $[0,4]$ and Domain of $y$ is $[0,4]$.

How I can determine the supremum  $$ g(x) = \sup_y f(x, y)$$ and infimum $$h(y) = \inf_xf(x, y)$$ of the function.

For $g(x)$ I guess I find derivate of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ which turns out to be $2(x-2)$ and for $h(y)$ i find derivate of $f(x,y)$ with respect to which turns out to be $2(y-2)$

Comment: It may help to first determine the infimum and supremum of $(x-2)^2$ and $(y-2)^2$ first.

Comment: please include your attempt.

Comment: For g(x) i guess i find derivate of f(x,y) with respect to x which turns out to be 2(x-2) and for h(y) i find derivate of f(x,y) with respect to which turns out to be 2(y-2)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this is a separable problem, the $x$ and $y$ can be optimized independently.

$$g(x) =\sup_y f(x,y) = (x-2)^2 + \sup_y (y-2)^2 =(x-2)^2+4$$

$$h(y) =\inf_x f(x,y) = \inf_x(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 =(y-2)^2$$